# operationalError at admin/.... at most 64 tables in a join

Tags: django, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am facing problem:

```
operationalError at /admin... at most 64 tables in a join
```

I am using `sqlite` db. Please see code and help me.

```py
class ReagentInventory(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manufacturing_unit = models.ForeignKey(ManufacturingUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ManufacturingPlant = models.ForeignKey(ManufacturingPlant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reagent_name = models.ForeignKey(Reagent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    storage_location = models.ForeignKey(StorageLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_stock = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=10, )
    measuring_unit = models.ForeignKey(MeasurementUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reagent_lot_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    reagent_mother_lot_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    challan_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mother_expiry_date = models.DateField()
    assigned_expiry_date = models.DateField()
    received_date = models.DateField()
    opening_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    number_of_container = models.IntegerField()
    packing_mode = models.ForeignKey(PackingMode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manufacturing_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reagent Inventories'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reagent_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reagent_name
```

Comment: Please reformat your code. Also, what is the error message?

Comment: we would need the full error stacktrace to help you, because there it shows the exact line that raises the error.

Comment: Hi, I am sharing stack trace--                                                                     
https://dpaste.com/395B4EY7A